# How to edit the template method for IntellijIdea?

Tags: methods

how to set method template for IntellijIdea?

/**

- @param request
- @param response
- @param handler
- @param ex
- @return

*/
 @Override

protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)